# Gamma spectroscopy - Fitted Singlet

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy, experimental-technique, data-analysis, gamma-rays

I'm using some gamma acquisition and analysis software. When I ask the software to do some sort of Nuclide Identification, almost every single peak in the generated output is marked with "F". According to the key at the bottom of the output, "F" stands for "Fitted Singlet". I've tried googling it, and I get clothes. I tried googling it with "Spectroscopy" tacked on, and nothing really comes up at all.

Has anyone got any idea what "Fitted Singlet" means in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the [Apex-Gamma software](http://www.canberra.com/products/radiochemistry_lab/apex-gamma.asp)? If so, a *fitted singlet* is a line the software has identified as being a single distinct line rather than a peak in a region where there are multiple overlapping lines. As I recall, Apex-Gamma identifies lines that are overlapping by $M$ or $m$ (presumably for *multiplet*).

Comment: I am not. But that is the exact notation which my software uses. I'm using a basic version of GENIE. Thanks!!

Comment: @MattS: both GENIE and Apex-Gamma are made by the same company CANBERRA Industries, so it's not surprising they use the same notation.

Comment: Aha! Interesting to know. Our detector is a Canberra "off the shelf" model.

Answer (score 1):

That means that the peaks could be fit with single Gaussian, the simplest fit. They did not have to fit as a doublet (two lines close together). Ortec has a technical paper on line at [Deconvolution of Gamma-Ray Peak Doublets as a Function of Peak Separation and Relative Amplitude](http://www.ortec-online.com/download/Deconvolution-Gamma-Ray-Peak-Doublets-Function-Peak-Separation-Relative-Amplitude.pdf)